# Android Out of Memory with OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, out-of-memory, opengl-es-2.0

I'm developing an Android 2.2 application that uses OpenGL ES 2.0. All OpenGL ES stuff is implmented with C++.

I got this error when I try to load a texture:

```
02-02 13:03:03.210: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(4117): 1728000-byte external allocation too large for this process.
02-02 13:03:03.210: ERROR/dalvikvm(4117): Out of memory: Heap Size=6471KB, Allocated=3881KB, Bitmap Size=17023KB
02-02 13:03:03.210: ERROR/GraphicsJNI(4117): VM won't let us allocate 1728000 bytes
```

What I should check to fix this 'Out of Memory' problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code here, specially any allocation you're trying to do? And also the code that actually loads the texture.

Loading textures is a very common operation, I'd would also recommend searching for sample code on the net, in the case you don't want to post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, it looks like you're trying to load a 16MB bitmap file into memory. You should look into reducing the size of that image. Android only allocates a certain amount of memory for each process and it looks like you're going way over it.

Maybe look into some memory optimizations for Android as well?

Comment: No, bitmap is 192KB. It's a bmp file. Maybe I can try to change it to jpg or png.

Comment: If you look at your error, it's saying you're trying to allocate 16MB on the heap. It even says "Bitmap Size=17023KB". So it looks like it's something to do with the image processing. Are you using the BitmapFactory?

Comment: Sorry for delay. I'm using BitmapFactory. Is there any problem with it?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I'm not quite sure where the error could be coming from then since the BitmapFactory should be taking care of that stuff for you.